# In tmux how do I exit the command prompt without typing an invalid command?

Tags: tmux

I can't figure out how to get out of the command prompt state I sometimes end up in when I hit `cntrl+b :`. I do this sometimes by accident when I'm about switch panes and then want to go into the vim command prompt but end up in tmux. Right now I type nonesense and hit enter, but I just want to escape. The escape key doesn't do this. Is there another way?

Comment: It's not a pane I want to kill, it's the tmux command line mode. It's not a pane, it appears at the bottom when you do cntrl+b, :

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just hit <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> and you should be back in your last window.

Comment: ctrl-c is not great - tmux should accept escape instead, since ctrl-c can accidentally kill stuff that you don't want to kill - aka when your system has the focus on the wrong window ya know what im saying g

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I use the <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit the **Tmux** command prompt.

Comment: doesn't work on Ubuntu, just tried

Answer (score 2):

I just press 'Return' or 'Enter'. i.e. an empty command.  As innaM says `Ctrl-c` works well and also works for selection panes like the one to select which client to detach, `<Prefix> D`.

Comment: Based on Alexander Mills comment, `Return` appears to be a safer solution.

Comment: `Return` does not work for me on macOS - `Escape` does.